# Add dependency to builld.gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I want to use sdk provided by facebook. For that i have added repositories and dependencies in build.gradle.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral() 
}
dependencies { 
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
}
```

When I rebuild the project, Error(23,13) is thrown.I have google it but unable to solve the problem. After that I downloaded facebook sdk manually and tried to import it into my project.This time "Error:(15, 0) Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' on project ':facebook' ". Nothing works well. Can anyone help me solving this issue? Please......

Answer (score 0):

Configure your android build, target SDK versions like this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
         minSdkVersion 15
         targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}
```

Use versions that apply in your case.

Comment: why studio is unable to download facebook sdk automatically from 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0' ?

Comment: Have you tried adding jcenter() under repositories? It's the new default repository to be used with android gradle plugin.

Comment: No, instead I have added mavenCentral() given at facebook developer website.

Comment: when i add jCenter error occured. Gradle DSL method not found :'jCenter'.

Comment: when i add jCenter error occured. Gradle DSL method not found :'jCenter'. Possible causes:1.The project 'MyProject' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method. 2.The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.

Comment: It's jcenter(). Lowercase c besides which version of gradle and android gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: with jcenter() Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0